# Windows Task Manager Startup Apps empty

Tags: windows, windows-11, task-manager

Three weeks ago I upgraded from Windows 10 to 11 and I just happened to look at the Startup Apps section of the Task Manager and it is empty and says

> There are no startup items to display

There are plenty of posts regarding other users experiencing this problem that predates Windows 11. I'm not sure if my case occurred as part of the upgrade or not. Unfortunately, all the standard fixes for this are not working for me.  So I'm here looking for other options or ideas.  This isn't really causing a huge problem, but it would be nice if I could fix it.

Attempted fixes thus far:

- confirmed that both `shell:startup` and `shell:common startup` folders exist and have at least some shortcuts in them. Deleted `shell:startup` rebooted, recreated it, rebooted and restored shortcuts that were located in there.
- Performed `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image/ScanHealth` `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` `sfc /scannow` along with multiple reboots
- manually restarted Windows Explorer

There are also plenty of entries in the normal registry locations:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: I have 2 production Windows 11 Pro machines and 1 Insider machine.  The startup tab is not empty.  Upgrades from Windows 10 can go wrong.  Try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link and Keep Everything

Comment: Try Sysinternals' AutoRuns, from MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), for a **much** more complete view of all items that start on their own. As for Task Manager, does it show no Startups when run both as Administrator and as lower-level user? If so, check for malware (trying to hide itself).

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. Task Manager is fine on Production as I noted. No items in Startup now in Windows 11 Insider.  Are you using Insider mode for Windows 11.  It will likely get fixed soon.

Comment: @John that's really helpful to know about your Insider system having an issue too. I turned off Insider a little while ago, but still waiting for a newer release to come out to bring it back onto the standard release channel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue did in fact turn out to be a bug introduced through Windows 11 Insider Builds. By uninstalling all the Beta enablement packages and deleting the registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost` , I was dropped out of Insider and back onto public Build 22621.1848 at which point this issue was resolved.  The issue is still resolved up through 22621.2361.